# How to make textarea position from the top left

Tags: html, css

So I have a webpage with an h3 element next to a textarea element:

```
<h3>Notes:</h3> <textarea></textarea>
```

and I have the h3 display set to inline-block.
This is what it looks like:
[image]

I want the h3 to be positioned and the top of the textarea like so:
[image]

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mre]! Show us your html/css and own attempt!

Comment: @0stone0 I provided all my html and css code. I'm confused as to what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.
Use flex container and set `margin: 0` to `h3`.
Because h3 has `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`
Of cause, `h1` to `h6` and `p` also has those margins.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Note:</h3>
  <textarea col="10" row="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 style="vertical-align: top;
text-align: left;">Notes:</h3> <textarea></textarea>
<!-- Use this vertical align css -->
```

Or else you can call the same css by internal method